# Netbeans GUI development sizing issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I'm having trouble using CardLayout with a JPanel inside of a JScrollPane. Basically I have a main JFrame and a JPanel inside of a JScrollpane, and then a whole bunch of different JPanels that are acting as 'cards' and pop up on different button clicks. The issue is, that some panels aren't scrollable all the way down to the bottom in the JScrollPane, they only scroll to the point of the initial panel.

Can anybody with some experience with NetBeans tell me how to make sure that each panel is fully scrollable in the scroll pane? If you only know the java code for setting this option I'd appreciate that too.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's a Netbeans issues per say.  Instead of putting the `CardLayout` pane into a `JScrollPane`, put the panel's that appearing inside the `CardLayout` inside their own `JScrollPane`s.  You may need to `invalidate` the view port that the `CardLayout` pane is sitting on when you switch "cards" to try and encourage the view port to update along with the `CardLayout` pane

Comment: Another suggestion IMHO -unless you are an expert at Swing- build the GUI yourself without the help of the IDE, you learn way more in the process

Comment: What version of NetBenas are you using?